# Show snackbar in front of Dialog

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am using the following method to show `SnackBar` in my app.

```
public static void showSnackBar( String msg, View view) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

I want to show `SnackBar` in front of `Dialog`(not at the bottom of `Dialog` but at bottom of `Activity`). As of now if I call `snackbar.show()` it will show `SnackBar` behind `Dialog` like this.

[image]

I just want to bring to the front and bottom of the `Activty`.Is there any way to show like that?

Comment: Dialog is showing over your View, but SnackBar is containing in your View. So it is not possible using SnackBar and Dialog

Comment: can you add more detail on how you calling showSnackBar message and where is the view, which you pass in this method

Comment: I pass Activity's root view to the above method.

Comment: Have you tried passing view from the dialog ?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi if i pass Dialog's root view, then SnackBar will show at the  bottom of Dialog.

Comment: You want that in front of the dialog. Can you share some image for that for better understanding ?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi image added. It is the current situation. I want snackbar to front at same position

Comment: @shine_joseph please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Make your **dialog layout fullscreen** with transparent background and keep your dialog content inside it and than while showing the snackBar give rootview of the dialog layout.

That might help you.

Comment: Already tried this method and it works. The problem with this method is that I have to edit each every Dialog layout xml as I am using custom layout for each Dialog.

Comment: I think this is the only way.  As i have also tried with the dialog.window.decorView but it keeps prompting the snackbar at the end of the dialog only and not on the screen's bottom

Comment: So either you have to go with the fullScreen or go with the toast.